# Float my 'form' box to right of the container in 'top brown div'

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I am using Bootstrap 2 - for some reason the login box doesn't float correctly to the right - I have tried various combinations but to no avail... any suggestions..

I've added a jsfiddle - but i've not added the bootstrap.css as I am unsure how to add these within the jsfiddle editor

http://jsfiddle.net/d5e7dqL7/

This is the form I am trying to position to the right (note I am using bootstrap and the container class)

```
        <form>
          <label class="login-label username">Username</label>
          <input value="Username" class="login-field username" />
          <label class="login-label password">Password</label>
          <input value="Password" class="login-field password" />            
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

using bootstraps grid system should help your out immensely.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem